# New line in puttext for two diffrent commands

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to write text on a previwe window , 
in one part of the programe I have

```
cv2.putText(cimg, par_x+par_y+par_h ,(50,50), font, 1,(255,255,255),1)
```

which is writing what I want, 
and I want to add on it in another function un the program another text,

```
cv2.putText(cimg,"please allow landing",(50,50), font, 1,(255,255,255),1)
```

when I do this I have the texts covering each other

how do I start a new line between those texts ? 
I'v been trying to use `'\n'` in all kinnda way but all it dose is printing '?' on the window

(I'm using python 2.7 and opencv on raspbery pi 2 )

Comment: Can't you just increase the y coordinate of the text?

Comment: I think this is already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27647424/opencv-puttext-new-line-character)

Comment: so tnx to sudomakeinstall2 , i'v put in the second puttext                                          cv2.puttext (cimg,"pleases allow landing " , (50,100) , font , 1,(255,255,255),1)